# NSLog всех действий пользователя

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток.

Задача состоит в следующем. Необходимо написать класс(либо несколько) после подключения которого к проекту(один раз) все действия пользователя выводились в лог.
То есть, пользователь нажал на кнопку в лог вывело *"нажата кнопка1"*, перешел на другой **ViewController** *"переход на ViewController1"* и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать для решения этой задачи или может есть уже что то готовое.

Заранее спасибо.

**P.S.** Есть ли метод который вызывается при любом взаимодействии пользователя с интерфейсом? Можно ли его переопределить для всего проекта?

Comment: Пишите в каждом действии NSLog да и все :) зачем классы создавать? Всеравно эти классы придется вызывать в местах где нажал пользователь что либо.
Есть более крутая идея. Берете все стандартные классы и заварачиваете в свои декораторы в которых будет NSLog. А потом уже пишете свое приложение просто вызывая super методы Вашего дикоратора.
А если вопрос стоит в дебаге, то кучка решений есть на [гитхабе][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&nwo=square%2FPonyDebugger&q=debug&ref=cmdform&search_target=global&type=Repositories

Comment: Чую рантаймом попахивает... Мои знания говорят, что без изменения кода ну ни как. Кроме одного написать на C/C++ обвертку всего проекта и при помощи рантайма мониторить все вызовы и обсервить действия пользователя. НО это ппц как не правильно.

Comment: Как минимум классы нужно переписывать, чтоб укзать где действие произвел пользователь, а где нет.

Comment: Еще как варинт навесить KVO на интересующие методы, но тоже надо классы дописывать. По мне ТЗ не правильное и попахивает хаком.

Comment: Задача поставлена так,чтобы инициализировать класс только один раз, и больше не вносить изменения в код программы.

Comment: Тогда можно написать некий класс, который бы в инициализацию на вход принимал класс для обсервинга, рантайм функцией перебирал все свойства и подвешивал их обсервинг:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html
Вот еще может пригодиться рантайм инъекции методов: http://theocacao.com/document.page/327

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Но тогда, на сколько я понял, для каждого класса нужно будет вызывать инициализацию. То есть в проекте 10 классов и для каждого нужно создать объект класса для логирования. Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

Коментарии кончились :(

> Спасибо, попробую. Но тогда, на
>   сколько я понял, для каждого класса
>   нужно будет вызывать инициализацию. То
>   есть в проекте 10 классов и для
>   каждого нужно создать объект класса
>   для логирования. Я правильно понял?

Да. Ну можно конечно извартиться по сильней, и рантаймом просканировать все классы, но тут я уже не подскажу, так как нужен очень большой скил в райнтайме.
Нашел только [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149505/ios-getting-all-classes-in-a-bundle-or-loaded-app) и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183136/get-all-subclasses-of-uiview-in-runtime-in-objective-c)

**UPD.**

> Есть ли метод который вызывается при любом взаимодействии пользователя с интерфейсом? Можно ли его переопределить для всего проекта?

Попробуйте, этот [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444281/887325).

**UPD1.**
Во метод тача возвращает-то UIView, тоесть того на ком тачнули ;)

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Апдейтнул. Может, действительно, достаточно будет знать UIVIew объек и звернуть его в NSLog и показывать? И будет выводить в косноиль что-нить: "Тачнули по объекту <MPKruglyakView: 0x14573a40; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x14573b20>> "

Comment: Таким образом можно перегрузить только UIApplication и "водка пей, зебля валяйся"

Comment: Обязательно попробую, еще интересный вариант по второй ссылке с reflection. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Вам спасибо за интересные таски )